# How to show the rich content written in QuillJS to public visitors?

Tags: javascript, quill

I know I can get the innerHTML of the editor when the writing is in progress and save it to the server. Then just paste it to the public visitor's page. I understand this is the case with most rich text editors. But what is the point of Delta in this case?

Quill gives me some JSON stuff. I can send it to the server very easily. But how can I show the rich content to the user? Will I show the user a QuillJS editor instance that has no toolbars and in read-only mode, instantiated with the Delta which came from the server?

Comment: did you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

> show the user a QuillJS editor instance that has no toolbars and in read-only mode, instantiated with the Delta which came from the server?

you can use it like this, and I think Use case of Quill with delta is something like google docs and not really to be used for a use case like a blog post editor.

There is another solution and it is to find quill delta to html library, there are many and some of them are pretty good check suggestions in this [thread](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/993)